# Is it possible to make loading = 'lazy' work in <img /> with X axis?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I used the feature [img lazy loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading#Images_and_iframes) for page with X axis scroll. But it works incorrect, images start loading only when they already appear on the page, instead of doing it earlier.

Example:

[image: example]

```js
function l(num) {
  document.getElementById('log').innerText += "loaded #" + num + " image\n";
}
```

```css
.images {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-x: visible;
  border: 1px solid magenta;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#log {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/300/150?1" height="150" width="300" onload="l(1)" />
  <img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/300/150?2" height="150" width="300" onload="l(2)" />
  <img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/300/150?3" height="150" width="300" onload="l(3)" />
  <img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/300/150?4" height="150" width="300" onload="l(4)" />
  <img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/300/150?5" height="150" width="300" onload="l(5)" />
  <img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/300/150?6" height="150" width="300" onload="l(6)" />
  <img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/300/150?7" height="150" width="300" onload="l(7)" />
</div>
<div id="log" />
```

I have come to the conclusion that this only works for images that are below the current point on the Y axis.

**How do you do this for the Y axis?**

### UPD: 04.03.2021

lazy work with X axis. But lazy work ONLY in main "body" scroll! When I make any `div` with `overflow: auto` as result lazy loading doesn't work at all!

Comment: Use an [`IntersectionObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver)

Answer (score 1):

You can use IntersectionObserver like this

```
const lazyInit = (element, fn) => {
    const config = {
      rootMargin: '0px 0px 50px 0px',
      threshold: 0
    };
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          observer.disconnect(); //drop observer and run the function {fn}
          fn();
        }
      });
      
    }, config);
    observer.observe(element);
  };
  document.querySelectorAll("img[data-src]").forEach(img => {
    lazyInit(img, function() {
      preloadImage(img);
    });
  });
  function preloadImage(img) {
    const src = img.getAttribute('data-src');
    if (!src) { return; }
    img.src = src;
  }
```

Then you must replace the *src* attribute of the img with *data-src*.

The img elements should look something like this

```
<img data-src="https://picsum.photos/300/150?1" height="150" width="300" />
```

The important thing here is the property *rootMargin*. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/rootMargin).

I hope this helps